# Class cross referencing?

Tags: python, c++, class, inheritance

I come from a C++ background and I am a bit lost without the whole pointer concept in python. Or at least it's unclear.
For instance, I want to create a game of tick tack toe using OOP in Python. I have a couple classes like so:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.board = [['','',''],
                      ['','',''],
                      ['','','']]
        self.players = [player1, player2]

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, game, marking):
        self.game = game
        self.marking = marking  # either 'X' or 'O'
```

It seems obvious that the game needs to have a reference to the two players and that a player is also part of a game, and should, therefore, have a reference to the game. However, the above code doesn't work because there is no way I can create a player without a creating a game first. But to create a game I need two players.
I could add in these references afterwards by doing something like: `player.game = some_game_reference` but this seems unpythonic and tedious to keep up with.

What is the best and most pythonic way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Things like `object`, `player1` et al _are_ effectively pointers. They are not values, as they would be in C++.

Comment: Why would the player need to know about the game? The game consists of a board and two players. The game knows whose turn it is and the state of the board. No need for the player to know the game.

Comment: @NeilButterworth They are pointers in CPython, but not necessarily in every implementation, right? In Python itself every variable is a reference to an object, but different than the one in C++.

Comment: It's pretty rare in python that you need both objects to have a reference to one another. When you do actually need that, usually one of them contains the other and will usually set the reference to itself on the other, most often directly (at this point the objects are tightly coupled already anyway).

Comment: Because if there's multiple games how will I find what game a specific player is... Well playing? I need a reference both ways.

Comment: @MaxSmith> in what context? Just try building your whole project without that back reference and you'll probably find out it's not needed. Because any code that handles a player in a way will have a reference to the game already.

Comment: If you create a list of games, you can query each game if it contains a specific player. That way one player can even participate in multiple games and is not limited to just one game. Or build a class ``Casino`` to keep track which player is playing which game.

Comment: Honestly, you shouldn't be thinking about pointers at all in Python. It's a much higher level language than that. There are no actual pointer types, but "underneath the hood", you can think of Python passing around pointers to `Py_Object` structs. But honestly, you should just read Ned Batchelder's [Facts and Myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just have one class or the other updates its arguments. For example, create the players first, then have the game update the players with itself:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.board = [['','',''],
                      ['','',''],
                      ['','','']]
        self.players = [player1, player2]
        player1.game = self
        player2.game = self
        player1.marking = 'X'
        player2.marking = 'O'  

# Neither game nor marking make sense to set initially, until
# the players are added to a game.
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

p1 = Player()
p2 = Player()

g = Game(p1, p2)
```

(Whether you *need* this kind of coupling is, as others have pointed out, a separate design issue.)

Just to show the other direction is just as feasible:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, game, marking):
        self.game = game
        self.marking = marking
        game.players.append(self)

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [['','',''],
                      ['','',''],
                      ['','','']]

g = Game()
p1 = Player(g, 'X')
p2 = Player(g, 'O')
```

Hopefully, though, you'll agree that it makes more sense for the game to assign each player a marking. Here, you might try to add more than 2 players to a game, or add two `X` or two `O` players.

Comment: This is very helpful thanks. I will see if other answers are posted but this seems to solve my problem. I didn't know I could assign self to a variable. Would you say there is a better way of doing this? The comments above point out that usually something like this isn't needed but in my mind this way I can create some sort of graph (the datastructure) and possibly have multiple games per player. Thx!

Comment: It really depends on how your application is structured, but I would agree that you should *strive* to make the `Player` class not need any information about the game(s) the player is involved in. As for `self`, there is nothing special about that name; you could use any name you want, but `self` is conventional. It simply refers to the object passed as the (implicit) first argument of any instance method. Any method call `obj.method(...)` is equivalent to `type(obj).method(obj, ...)`; the argument `self` (or whatever name you use) is bound to `obj`.